# Client side LESS files in Bootstrap cannot be found

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, client-side

Hi I am trying to use LESS with bootstrap using the clientside js method of compiling to avoid using command line etc. I have included the latest version of LESS.js plus a link to the neccessary LESS files that come with bootstrap but when I load the page I get this error:

```
FileError: 'http://localhost/boyd/assets/less/bootstrap.less' wasn't found (404)
```

Here is the code used in the header:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/less/variables.less" />
 <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/js/less-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Try getting to your bootstrap.less file in your browser. Once you verify the path works in your browser, then modify your `script` tag with the correct path.

Answer (score 3):

It may be caused by MIME types security at the IIS level. Make sure that your website in IIS manager has ".less" as  a registered MIME type (open IIS manager, click your site in left tree panel, look for "MIME Types" item at the right pane, then click it).

If there is no ".less" registered, just add this as a "text/css", for example.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
     <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />
     </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>`
in my web.config